# When to use NSString stringWithFormat;

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

While I am reading how to utilize Sqlite in iOS, I reached the following line

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM 
tableName"];
```

I googled some tutorials and documentations to find out why the following method were used instead of a regular NSString object:

```
stringWithFormat
```

Why we could not use something like the following since there is no need to specify and special format such as %@ or %d?:

```
NSString *query = @"SELECT * FROM tableName";
```

Comment: You can use it directly(NSString *query = @"SELECT * FROM tableName";)  provided if there is no %@/%d or any %character.

Comment: If you aren't going to get values from variables, `@"SELECT * FROM tableName"` this should be fine. If you are going to replace the name of table at runtime, you would use `stringWithFormat`

Comment: When ever some values from server then and some value want to conversation into string then stringWithFormat method is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aren't going to get values from variables, `@"SELECT * FROM tableName"` this should be fine.

If you are going to replace the name of table at runtime, you would use `stringWithFormat`

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM %@", myTableName];
```